# Accessing SSH through web

Tags: ubuntu, ssh

I was given a website to connect to an SSH server but my browser says it doesn't exist(both in Windows and Ubuntu). When I do the

```
ssh username@website.com
```

command in the command line it works fine.

Is there something I should be doing for my system to be able to access the website itself?

Comment: Can you confirm that you have a web server installed on the server "website.com"
you will need something like apache, nginx or something else serving http/https.
The other issue, you will need to make sure that you have the port open to the world e.g. tcp 80/443. If you have firewalls or routers that need to have port forwarding configured you will need to do that.

Comment: Thank you!Also,good job on looking past me writing website instead of server.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot access ssh directly from the browser. You would need to connect using the terminal, with the `ssh username@website.com` command.

If you are looking for a website hosted at `website.com` then, navigate there using the browser. If you are looking to host the website, once you ssh in, applications such as apache and nginx handle hosting the website.

Answer (score 0):

For starters, to check whether the website really is accepting SSH connections you could use an online port scanner form the list here:

https://duckduckgo.com/?q=port+scanner+online&ia=web

Then enter the address you were given (website.com) and tell it to look at port 22. It's possible for the person to have set up SSH on a different port, but if they haven't said its on a different port it should be on 22.

Once you have determined that SSH is running you can look at ways of connecting to it.